# Disable doze mode when countdown timer is running

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, android-doze

I am developing an app In which `countdown-timer` is running when user start timer Everything is perfect Now the issue is timer stuck when user lock his device (doze mode or sleep or idle).

Please help if anyone knows that how to prevent our app from doze mode when timer is active.

Comment: use `AlarmManager` instead of "countdown-timer" (whatever it is)

Comment: But I need timer to show time example if user select  1 hour the its shows on UI 59 Min 3 second left....so on Is there any other way to handle timer

Comment: show where? in some activity? if so, use it only inside your activity

Comment: Yes, the app is timer app user can start, stop , extend timer now I need only when timer is running then disable doze mode.